# Merge two dataframes in pandas based on the same column name values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to merge two dataframes. I want to add new columns to existing dataframe **one** as expected the result below. Please kindly help me to do this.

one:

```
 Name      Status  Dummy
Kumar     Done       1
Shankar   Progress   1
Shankar   Done       2
sekar      no        0
```

Two:

```
Name     Status    Remarks  Temp
Shankar   Progress  Good     5
Shankar    Done     Very     6
```

Expected Result :

```
  Name    Status     Dummy    Remarks   Temp
  Kumar     Done       1                 0
  Shankar   Progress   1        Good     5
  Shankar   Done       2        very     6
  sekar      no        0                 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left join with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then replace missing values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Name','Status'], how='left')
df['Temp'] = df['Temp'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df['Remarks'] = df['Remarks'].fillna('')

print (df)
      Name    Status  Dummy Remarks  Temp
0    Kumar      Done      1             0
1  Shankar  Progress      1    Good     5
2  Shankar      Done      2    Very     6
3    sekar        no      0             0
```

Comment: Could you plz tell me that how to insert new rows in expected result . i am trying append but its not working for me .df2 = pd.DataFrame([['kishore','progress',1,'Poor',0],['s','Done',2,'good',0]],columns=list(df.columns.values))
df.append(df2)

Comment: :( i also tried the same thing which i metioned the above comment

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: @PythonTeam - `i am trying append but its not working for me` - can you explain more? Problem with data?